# Swift: How to make sure that the button returns image to previous state

Tags: swift, button

I'm building iOS app I have a button that if pressed once it should change its image. If I press it once again it should go back to the original image. I know I can easily do it by checking if it's the second image on button press but I'm pretty sure that there is a better approach to this.

Comment: Show what you have tried so far. Is this for iOS, macOS, tvOS, or watchOS?

Comment: I'ts ios as I said I know how I can do it I'm coming  from javascript background and here is how I would usually do it there 

if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            myLight.enabled = !myLight.enabled;

Comment: No, you never said it's iOS, just that it's Swift. And please [edit] your question with all relevant details.

Comment: Updated it :) Could you please let me know If there is such way it Swift

Comment: You forgot to add your code to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep one extra Boolean variable to maintain the state of the button. Modify the bool value on every click. On `didSet` of the variable, you can update your button Image. If you have multiple states of the button you can have one enum.

```
private var isButtonActive: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        let image = isButtonActive ? "Image1": "Image2"
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    }
}

func buttonClick() {
    isButtonActive = !isButtonActive
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's all that I needed! :)